# Custom mouse cursor appearing blurry

Tags: javascript, svg, cursor, mouse, blurry

I am trying to set a SVG as custom mouse cursor using the cursor property
and using data URI but that appears blurry. I don't know what to do. The SVG itself appears fine if I render it elsewhere but when I use it as windows mouse cursor it appears blurry. Please help!!

I have tried  changing the size the SVG currently is 32x32 and when I make it bigger
to 128x128 then the blurriness goes

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)